# Send email (Visualforce Email Template) included Visualforce component which render after update action

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template

Want to send email after update with multiple records
I have used Visulaforce Email Template with Visulaforce component having controller.

Visulaforce component that getting list of record in table from same controller

**ViewAvalibleRidesController.cls**

**getAssignRideList()** for return list of rides

**ridesids** is list of Ids which is getting after the update

```
   public PageReference assigndriver(){

          try{
              if(lstRide.size() > 0 && !isExideLimit)
                  update lstRide;
                  AssignedMultipleRides(ride.Volunteer__c,ridesids);
          }catch(Exception ex){
              ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
          }
    return null;
  }
  public void AssignedMultipleRides(String VID,Set<Id> RIDE_IDS){
      SendEmailController sm = new SendEmailController();
      String rideDetail = '';

      if(RIDE_IDS.size() > 0 && VID != NULL){
          Volunteer__c v = [SELECT Name FROM Volunteer__c WHERE Id  = :VID];
          driverName = v.Name;
          getAssignRideList();
          AssignedMultipleRidesEmail(VID);
      }
  }
  public List<Ride__c> getAssignRideList(){

      List<Ride__c> rList = new List<Ride__c>();
      System.debug('Ids'+ridesids);
      rList = [SELECT Appointment_Date_Time_Formula__c,Client__r.Name,Duration__c FROM Ride__c WHERE Id In :(ridesids)]; 
      return rList;

     }
```

public void **AssignedMultipleRidesEmail** (String VOLUNTEER_ID) {

```
             EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id,HtmlValue,Subject From EmailTemplate Where DeveloperName = 'Assigned_Multiple_Ride'];
             Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] theEmails  = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{};

                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {};
                User users = [Select Id,Username,Name FROM User WHERE Username = 'xyz@gmail.com'];

                    if(users.Username != null || users.Username != ''){

                       toAddresses.add(users.Username);
                       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                       mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                       mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                       mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
                       mail.setTargetObjectId(users.Id);
                       theEmails.add(mail);
                    }
                Messaging.Email[] allMails = new Messaging.Email[]{};

                if(!theEmails.isEmpty()){
                    for(Integer i = 0; i < theEmails.size(); i++){
                        allMails.add(theEmails.get(i));
                    }
                }      
          try{
               Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail( allMails );
          }catch(Exception ex){
              System.debug('Excepetion'+ex);
          }
  }
```

**Visualforce component**

**AssignMultipleComponent.cmp**
Used ViewAvalibleRidesController.cls as controller with access="global"

```
       <apex:outputText value="Hello "></apex:outputText>
       <apex:outputText value="{!driverName}"></apex:outputText><br/><br/>

       <apex:outputText value="You are assigned the following rides:"> 
       </apex:outputText>
        <table border="0" >

            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!AssignRideList}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Rider Name:</b> {!cx.Client__r.Name} <br/>
                <b>Ride Date:</b> {!cx.Appointment_Date_Time_Formula__c} 
                <br/>
                <b>Ride Duration:</b> {!cx.Duration__c}<br/><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>
```

[image: Email Tenplate]

But at time of sending email its release the value and gave an empty list in email

What i have missed or there is another way to do the same?

Comment: 1) you should show the VF component invocation from the email template, VF component markup, especially the assignTo variable; and the rest of the component controller - use [edit]

Comment: @cropredy: I have included code, please check

Comment: i don't see the email template (essential bits only please); or the start of the VF component with the apex:attribute settings

Comment: @cropredy: I have included email template, please check

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here to explore

1. The VF email template needs to reference a target object via the `relatedTo` attribute. This identifies the object from whence merge fields will be populated
2. The reference to the component needs to pass some value to an `apex:attribute` defined in the VF component `AssignMultipleComponent`. This would look something like this: c:AssignMultipleComponent foo="{!relatedTo.somemergefield}"/> where `someMergeField` is a field on the target object that the email message (alert+message) is associated to
3. The apex:attribute binds the value passed from the VF Email template (and hence, the value from the target object) to a public property in the VF component's controller. Thus, the controller has what it needs to query from the database

Please consult [Creating a VF Email Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_creating.htm) and especially [Custom Component attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_elements_attributes.htm)

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for the answer, I have tried as you have suggested but at the time of `assignTo` and `relatedTo` its not accept Set of IDs.

Comment: Pass a single ID and let component controller requery.

Comment: I thought it is wrong way So, I have modify code and replace Visualforce Email Template With Custom Email Template without letterhead and use String in stand of List and set that string on Custom Email template and its work fine @cropredy